# Curvature based derivation of Schwarzschild Metric

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, curvature

I'm a third year maths undergrad and I'm trying to find (and follow) a curvature based derivation of the [Schwarzschild metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric), if there exists such a proof?

Comment: it is conventonially derived as the only spherically symmetric metric solution for the vacuum. This seems to me like perfectly simple approach. Does that not satisfy you?

Comment: If you like this question you may also enjoy reading [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21705/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: Unfortunately not! I'm writing a project on minimal surfaces - so the curvature plays a big role :-)

Comment: So what would you mean by a 'curvature based derivation'?

Comment: Since the idea of a geometric manifold with associated metric tensor, as well as other derived quantities such as the Riemann curvature tensor, Ricci tensor, etc., it would seem hard to find a derivation that IS NOT a curvature based derivation.  So what exactly are referring to when you say curvature-based?