# Schwarzschild Solution

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, tensor-calculus

I'm able to derive the [Schwarzschild solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Schwarzschild_Solution) under the assumptions that the metric is (1) static (2) spherically symmetric and that the space is the vacuum. However, I have read that the Schwarzschild solution can be found assuming only that the metric is a spherically symmetric vacuum. How would the Schwarzschild solution be derived under these weaker conditions?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff%27s_theorem_(relativity) If you are actually 13, good job.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was 13, though it was a week before by 14th birthday.

Comment: How are you learning GR? Texts or online resources?

Comment: GR texts and pdfs that I have found

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21705/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a theorem which states that any spherically symmetric solution to the vacuum equations is also necessarily static and asymptotically flat. It is known as [Birkhoff's theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff%27s_theorem_(relativity)) Chapter 4 of Straumann (2013) contains a full proof.

Comment: Also Carroll's GR book.

Comment: Indeed. OP has claimed to read this book, but I think it's hard to read a book and miss the content of 7 pages.

Comment: Yeah, never mind the bragging etc. Never take anything on the internet at face value ;)