# Birkhoff Theorem proof reference

Tags: general-relativity, symmetry, metric-tensor, resource-recommendations, coordinate-systems

I am looking for a reference with a clear (and easy to understand) proof of [Birkhoff's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff%27s_theorem_%28relativity%29) in general relativity.

Comment: References are e.g. given in [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21705/2451) Phys.SE post.