# Birkhoff's theorem proof of step

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, symmetry, metric-tensor

In E. Poisson's book "A relativist's toolkit" he says we can set $\psi$ to $0$ without off of generality and i can't work out why.

Picture attached.[image]

Comment: This question is e.g. explained in [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21705/2451) Phys.SE post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equations imply $\partial_r\psi=0$ so that $\psi$ is a function only of $t$. Then, the metric takes the form
$$
ds^2 =- e^{2\psi(t) } f dt^2 + \cdots 
$$
We can now redefine the coordinate $t$ so that
$$
dt' = e^{\psi(t)} dt
$$
Then,
$$
ds^2 =-f dt'^2 + \cdots 
$$
We can now remove the prime superscript. We then retrieve the original metric with $\psi = 0$.

In other words, the author means that $\psi$ can be set to zero by choosing an appropriate time coordinate.