# What is the exact meaning of the Birkhoff theorem?

Tags: general-relativity, symmetry, metric-tensor

The [Birkhoff theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff%27s_theorem_(relativity)) states that the isotropic metric is time-independent. What is the exact meaning of this? Does it mean that for the isotropic source, the metric in any coordinate system is time-independent? Or Does it mean that there exists a specific coordinate system in which the metric is time-independent? It is very confusing.

Comment: It's the latter. I can always redefine the time coordinate in some weird way (such as $t \to 2t + t^2 + \sin(t)$) so that everything is formally dependent on $t$.

Answer (score 1):

1. The latter. There exists a specific coordinate system in which the metric is time-independent. Obviously it is possible to introduce time-dependence in the metric via a change of coordinates. For further details and the exact  meaning of the [Birkhoff theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff%27s_theorem_(relativity)), see my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/22590/2451).
2. Also note that [Birkhoff theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff%27s_theorem_(relativity)) states that a spherically symmetric solution of the vacuum [EFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations) must be [static](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_spacetime), i.e. it admits a global, non-vanishing, timelike Killing vector field that is irrotational. Note that this is a coordinate-independent statement.