# Solutions locally isometric to Schwarzchild

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, symmetry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

In *Relativity and Singularities,* Natário states that

> Any vacuum solution admitting $O(n)$ as an isometry group is locally isometric to $M=\mathbb{R}^2\times S^{n-1}$ (with the Schwarzchild metric).

Why is that so? It doesn't seem obvious to me, and I found no precise proof (from the mathematical point of view) around the web.

Comment: This is addressed by Birkhoff's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff%27s_theorem_(relativity)

Comment: Indeed, I had looked into Birkhoff's theorem, but found no clear proof of it. Wikipedia, for example, only loosely states it and proceeds to discussion of its implications.

Comment: The Wikipedia page features precise references (e.g. to Birkhoff's original work), so that should cover it. You might also find this in mathematically-oriented general relativity books (Ellis & Hawking, or Wald?)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21705/2451

Comment: Looking at it I'm not sure why having $O(n)$ as isometry group implies local isometry to $\mathbb{R}^2\times S^{n-2}$, nor why this is equivalent to Birkhoff's theorem.