# Criterion for a black hole in Anti-de Sitter background

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, event-horizon, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

Consider a Schwarzschild-Anti de Sitter (SAdS) metric

$$ds^2=-(1-\frac{2M}{r}+ k\, r^2 )\, dt^2+\frac{dr^2}{1-\frac{2M}{r}+k \,r^2}+r^2 d\Omega_2^2,     $$

with $M,k>0$. This solution has only one horizon, say $r_+>0$. Notice that $r_+\neq 2M$. Is $r_+$ the horizon of a black hole?

EDIT: I have tried to clarify / improve my question to the current version because the previous version seemed to be somewhat misleading.

EDIT II: I guess the answer is given by staring at the associated Penrose diagram, from which it can be easily obtained that there is no escape from inside the horizon $r_+$...

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking for. On the surface it sounds like you are asking for an Anti-deSitter version of the hoop conjecture (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoop_Conjecture). However, that is not even proven for the asymptotically flat version.

Comment: Differently put can you phrase more precisely what the flat space equivalent is of the answer that you are looking for?

Comment: For flat space we know that a star whose mass M is completely contained inside the domain corresponding to the Schwarzschildradius 2M is a black hole. What is the corresponding statement (criterion) for a "black hole" in an asymptotically anti-de Sitter space?

Comment: The Hoop conjecture in AdS asks for more than I do. I just would like to know a criterion regarding the particular metric of my post.

Comment: @kaffeeauf I changed my answer and wrote one down for your revised question. Have a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to OP v(2):**

Yes, "$r^+$" in your language is the horizon of the black hole. I am writing the black hole in $AdS_4$'s metric as

$$ds^2 = f(r)dt^2 - \frac{dr^2}{f(r)}-r^2 d\Omega^2,$$

where $f(r) = 1 - \frac{2M}{r} + \frac{r^2}{a^2}.$

The black hole's event horizon is given by the real roots of $g^{rr} = f(r) = 0$ (note the upper indices), which in this case is given by

$$r^3 +a^2r - 2Ma^2 = 0.$$

Note that $f(r)$ has the following behaviour:

1. $f(r) \to -\infty$, as $r \to 0^+$.
2. It has not extrema, $f'(r)=0 \implies r^3 = -Ma^2 <0.$
3. It has one inflection point: $f''(r) = 0 \implies r = (2Ma^2)^{1/3}.$

Therefore the **black hole has only one event horizon** given by:

$$r_h = (Ma^2)^{1/3} \left[ \left( 1 + \sqrt{1+\frac{a^2}{27M^2}}\right)^{1/3} + \left( 1 - \sqrt{1+\frac{a^2}{27M^2}}\right)^{1/3} \right].$$

One can invert this equation to obtain the expression for the mass:

$$M = \frac{r_h}{2} \left( 1 + \frac{r_h^2}{a^2}\right),$$

which is basically an inverse of $r_h$.

**Relationship of $r_h$ with $r_{Schwarz} = 2M$**

Let us compute the deviation of $r_h$ from $r_{Schwarz} = 2M$, if $\frac{M}{a} \ll 1$. Using the relation between $M$ and $r_h$, one can write

$$\frac{M}{a} = \frac{r_h}{2a}\left( 1 + \left(\frac{r_h}{a}\right)^2\right) \ll 1 \implies \frac{r_h}{a} \approx \frac{M}{a} \ll 1.$$

As a result we can write:

$$r_h = \frac{2M}{1+\frac{r_h^2}{a^2}} \approx 2M \left( 1 - \frac{r_h^2}{a^2}\right) = r_{Schwarz} \left( 1 - \frac{4M^2}{a^2}\right)$$

Clearly

1. $r_h \to r_{Schwarz}$ as $a \to \infty$.
2. $r_h \to 0$ as $M \to 0$.
3. $r_h \to (2Ma^2)^{1/3}$ as $M \to \infty$.

**Answer to OP v(1):**

1. A Schwarzchild black hole in AdS does not have stress energy, i.e. $T_{\mu\nu} = 0$. It satisfies the sourceless Einstein equations with a negative cosmological constant. So there is no "mass distribution" inside the horizon as you mentioned as the stress energy components are all zero everywhere (apart from the singularity). See the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdS_black_hole) for minor details. For a deeper discussion, see section 4 [of these notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.02744) where they start with the AdS metric (they start with a spherically symmetric asymptotic AdS solution) and compute all curvature components. Equations (4.7) and (4.8) demonstrate that the stress energy components are all zero. Consequently there are no stress energy components and as a result no "matter distribution" in the interior.
2. Birkhoff theorem states that there is an unique form solving the vacuum Einstein equations given spherical symmetry, which is the Schwarzchild solution. See this excellent [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/22590/50770) for more details.
3. Geometry wise the mass $M$ of any black hole is understood in the [ADM formalism.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADM_formalism#ADM_energy_and_mass) The correct way to understand the mass of a black hole is not to think that there is a "mass distribution" sitting in the interior, but there is an energy associated with the spacetime itself, as beautifully explained in the ADM formalism. In this formalism, the ADM mass is a way to define the energy of $d$ dimensional spacelike slices in $d+1$ dimensional spacetime. This definition naturally comes out of the [$d+1$ ADM decomposition of the Einstein-Hilbert Lagrangian](http://web.mit.edu/edbert/GR/gr11.pdf). See [these notes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0703035.pdf) for more details on the ADM decomposition.

Comment: The condition $T_{\mu\nu}=0$ you mention in point (1) is also true for the ordinary exterior Schwarzschild solution in the asymptotic flat background.

Comment: @kaffeeauf It is true everywhere, not just the exterior even in AdS. Static black holes like these are solution to vacuum Einstein equations.

Comment: I added some further sources, have a look.

Comment: In Section 4.2 of the paper you mention, the discussion is just about the value (root) of the horizon and some more mathematical properties. Statements regarding my questions are missing.

Comment: @kaffeeauf See the right side of equation (4.7). It is zero. All stress energy components are zero. So there is no mass distribution, which is contradictory to what you are asking in your question. What other statements do you have in your question?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you are trying to tell me. Even for the ordinary Schwarzschild black hole in flat space the field equations have a zero on the right hand side. Nevertheless, a definition of the black hole is possible in terms of the Schwarzschild radius 2M.

Comment: @kaffeeauf Ok you agree that there is a zero on R.H.S. So what is the mass distribution you are talking about? By, the way I told you exactly what is the physical meaning of $M$ in my 3rd point. Did you check the links? I think its unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I am afraid that I can not follow your argumentaion, especially regarding the ADM theme. Let me try this: Do you think that there can be a black hole in an AdS or not? If yes, what is the horizon from which no classical (non-QFT) particle can escape? Or do you think that there is not such kind of horizon?

Comment: The horizon you are talking about is called the event horizon. For the Ads Black hole metric you provided, it is a spherical horizon of radius $r_h$ as computed in @BruceLee 's answer.