# Help in derivation of Birkhoff's theorem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor, symmetry, coordinate-systems

> The most general spherically symmetric line element is of the form
> $$\mathrm{d}s^2=-A(r,t)\mathrm{d}t^2+2C(r,t)\mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}r+B(r,t)\mathrm{d}r^2+r^2(\mathrm{d}\theta^2+\sin^2{\theta}\mathrm{d}\phi^2).$$
> I am trying to show that with a transformation $t\rightarrow t+f(r,t)$ for some $f(r,t)$, the line element can be written as
> $$\mathrm{d}s^2=-A(r,t)\mathrm{d}t^2+B(r,t)\mathrm{d}r^2+r^2(\mathrm{d}\theta^2+\sin^2{\theta}\mathrm{d}\phi^2).$$

Using the transformation for $t$, I obtained

$$\mathrm{d}t'=\left(1+\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\right)\mathrm{d}t+\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\mathrm{d}r.$$

Using this equation, I substituted it into the general line element to obtain

\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d}s^2=&-A(r,t)\left(1+\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\right)^{-2}\mathrm{d}t'^{2}-A(r,t)\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\right)^2\left(1+\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\right)^{-2}\mathrm{d}r^2\nonumber\\
&+2A(r,t)\left(1+\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\right)^{-2}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\right)\mathrm{d}t'\mathrm{d}r\nonumber\\
&+2C(r,t)\left(1+\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\right)^{-1}\mathrm{d}t'\mathrm{d}r-2C(r,t)\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\right)\left(1+\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\right)^{-1}\mathrm{d}r^2+B(r,t)\mathrm{d}r^2\nonumber\\
&+r^2(\mathrm{d}\theta^2+\sin^2{\theta}\mathrm{d}\phi^2).
\end{align*}

Is the equation that is immediately above correct? How do I proceed to show that the line element can be written as $\mathrm{d}s^2=-A(r,t)\mathrm{d}t^2+B(r,t)\mathrm{d}r^2+r^2(\mathrm{d}\theta^2+\sin^2{\theta}\mathrm{d}\phi^2)$?

Comment: This is explained in footnote 1 of my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/22590/2451).

Comment: Is it possible for you to elaborate more on your method?

Comment: Do you have a specific question about it?