# Would Birkhoff's Theorem also apply for a field with negative energy density?

Tags: general-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, cosmological-constant

[Birkhoff's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff%27s_theorem_(relativity)) says that any spherically symmetric solution to the field equations must be the Schwarzschild metric. I'm wondering whether that could be generalized to a field with negative energy density?

Comment: Related: [Deriving Birkhoff's Theorem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21705/2451)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it wouldn't. Birkhoff's Theorem states not that any spherically symmetric solution to the field equations must be the Schwarzschild solution, but rather that any spherically symmetric solution to the *vacuum* field equations must be the Schwarzschild solution. If there is any non-negative energy density on spacetime and the Einstein Field Equations are assumed to hold, then that spacetime can't be Schwarzschild spacetime.

Notice that the Schwarzschild metric has $R_{\mu\nu} = 0$, and hence $R = 0$. As a consequence, the Einstein Equations lead to
$$\begin{align}
R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2} R g_{\mu\nu} &= 8 \pi T_{\mu\nu}, \\
0 &= 8 \pi T_{\mu\nu}, \\
T_{\mu\nu} &= 0.
\end{align}$$

If the stress-energy tensor is anything other than identically zero (including if one considers a non-vanishing cosmological constant), then the Schwarzschild metric is not a solution to the Einstein equations on that region where $T_{\mu\nu} \neq 0$.